# Eclipse - JBoss (Hibernate) tools not showing any tables

Tags: eclipse, oracle, hibernate, jboss

I want to use JBoss tools in Eclipse to generate java code from DDL.
I am using the following:
Oracle XE
Eclipse Helios (SpringSource version)
JBoss Tools

I've configured the hibernate.cfg.xml (as below) and created a sample application to insert and update records in XE and it works fine.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
      "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
      "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">admin</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">users</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <mapping resource="users.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

But when I select (in hibernate perspective) File->New->Hibernate console configuration, I get the following in the "Hibernate Configurations" window:

```
-Console
    +Configuration
    +Session Factory
    +Database
```

***Expanding the "Database" above shows "pending" for few seconds and then shows nothing. I expecting it to show the table names. I am struggling to find out the reason. There are no exceptions\errors in any of the log files, nothing on console, all XE services are running, hibernate configuration is correct because my sample app works.***

While creating the "console configuration" I created a new database connection and have done the "Test connection" and it shows "Ping successfully" message. I've used the following in the configuration:

```
hibernate.connection.url           jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
hibernate.dialect                           org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
hibernate.connection.driver_class   oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fixed it.. 
had to change the following

```
<property name="hibernate.default_schema">users</property>
```

to

```
<property name="hibernate.default_schema">USERS</property>
```

Comment: Hi, Am also facing this issue and I tried your solutions but its still not working for me... is there anything else I should be doing..

Comment: Thanks for the answer it pointed me in the right direction... I had the exact same issue but the problem for me was to change "hibernate.default_schema" to "hibernate.default_catalog" probably because I was using MySQL5 and not Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, then found out my database had no tables in it and felt embarrassed. After creating a quick table, it worked. Will never get that time back..